# Pip Requirements Permission Error Python 3.6.6

Tags: python, pip

When using pip to install from a requirements file with `pip install -r requirements.txt` I get `PermissionError`. How can I avoid this?

[image: ERROR INSTALLING requirements.txt]

Comment: Copy and paste the error message, not just a screenshot. From the error message, you don't have permissions to write to the path. `pip install --user -r requirements.txt`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you have Python installed in `Program Files`. You'll have constant permissions issues there. Uninstall it and reinstall somewhere else, like `C:/Python36` or another location of your choosing.

Alternatively, you could try running your terminal as an administrator and running the install from the elevated prompt. You'll likely have to do this every time you run something though, and this isn't good practice for security reasons.